# How to do line level logic in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that has a bunch of columns and I need to create a new column based on the row type but the logic will be different for each type of row.

My data looks like this:

| type | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c | 17 |
| 2 | e | f | g | 20 |
| 3 | i | j | k | 100 |

the logic for rows of type 1 is concatenating field1, field2, field3

the logic for rows of type 2 is concatenating field2, field3, field4

the logic for rows of type 3 is squaring field4

***The super important part***
I would like to avoid coding each type manually as there are hundreds of different types each with their own distinct logic that will change constantly. We enforce strict SDLC so deploying updates would be a nightmare. Ideally I would put this logic into a SQL table somewhere and then just somehow use the data in my pandas logic but I don't know how to do that sort of thing.

Example:

```
data = pd.read_sql(query) #above data
rules = pd.read_sql(query)
rules.head()
```

| Type | Rule |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | field1+field2+field3 |
| 2 | field2+field3+field4 |
| 3 | field4**2 |

```
for i in rules:
    data['output'] = data[filtered to i.type].apply(i.typeLogic)

data.head()
```

| output |
| --- |
| abc |
| fg20 |
| 10000 |

Comment: Can you define a dictionary like `{ 1:['field1','field2','field3'], 2:['field2','field3','field4'], 3:['field4'] }` and maintain it separate from concatenation?

Comment: If I'm following your suggestion, the idea would be to create a dictionary with the rules for each type? One of the sticking points is these rules change constantly and I cannot just change production code on the fly. How could I store this dictionary outside of the python code and use it within the python code?

Comment: How can you have a production process where the input conditions are constantly changing?

Comment: @Chris  I wish I could explain. Basically accounting. They are always changing how they want to aggregate data/show data/present data. It changes nearly every quarter. And it's always at close deadline.

Comment: Just ask those who are changing rules to maintain a json file somewhere and your production code can read it and you don’t need to worry changing the prod code.

Comment: @SomeDude Okay, how would you execute code written JSON? I added an example to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the rules to the data and use `eval` method to evaluate rules according to type

```py
# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': [1, 2, 3],
                   'field1': ['a', 'e', 'i'],
                   'field2': ['b', 'f', 'j'],
                   'field3': ['c', 'g', 'k'],
                   'field4': [17, 20, 100]})
# rules df
rules = pd.DataFrame({'type': [1, 2, 3],
                      'rule': ['field1+field2+field3', 'field2+field3+field4', 'field4**2']})

# merge the dfs to be able to do a rules lookup later
df = df.merge(rules, on='type')

# create a list in a loop
lst = []
for _, d in df.groupby("type"):
    # get the field columns
    f_cols = [c for c in d.columns if 'field' in c]
    # get the rule 
    r = d.rule.iat[0]
    # rules with + concatenates strings and ints, so convert such rows to string dtype
    if '+' in r:
        d[f_cols] = d[f_cols].astype(str)
    # evaluate the rule
    d['new'] = d[f_cols].eval(f"{r}", engine='python')
    # append to lst
    lst.append(d)
# concatenate all dfs in lst into a single df
res = pd.concat(lst)
res
```

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using:

```
cond1 = df['type'] == 1
cond2 = df['type'] == 2
cond3 = df['type'] == 3

result1 = df[['field1', 'field2', 'field2']].sum(1)
result2 = df[['field2', 'field3', 'field4']].astype('str').sum(1)
result3 = df['field4'] ** 2

df['result'] = np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3], [result1, result2, result3])
```

Output:

```
   type field1 field2 field3  field4 result
0     1      a      b      c      17    abb
1     2      e      f      g      20   fg20
2     3      i      j      k     100  10000
```

Comment: Hey gig 'em Aggies. So the part that I'm struggling with is how to get the desired logic from outside of my app. The logic changes every month and I cannot be redeploying a python script every period because someone wants to add one more column to a key or something simple like that. The logic somehow has to be stored somewhere else and executed. The part that I cannot figure out is how do I execute code that is stored in in a SQL database (or anywhere really) as python code. I know there is the exec function but I heard it shouldn't be used.

Comment: Howdy, Jarrod.  Gig'em! Hrm. It would help if your input dataframe has your logic in a column as a string.

Comment: Oh I can do that. I could have a sql table with the type and rule then just join to it. So if I had a table with a column that had the rules like field1+field2+field3, how would I apply the logic in the field to that row?

Comment: Create a small sample data set with that logic and we'll give you exact code.

Comment: Okay I added an example to the original question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your pandas dataframe, I'd define a function:

```
def rowwise(x):
    if x['type '] == 1:
        return x['field1 '] + x['field2 '] + x['field3 ']
    if x['type '] == 2:
        return x['field2 '] + x['field3 '] + str(x['field4'])
    if x['type '] == 3:
        return str(float(x['field4'])**2)
```

then apply it with the option `axis=1`

```
df.apply(rowwise, axis=1)
```

A couple of gotchas are that concatenation only works with strings, and the resulting column should have a consistent datatype.  That's why there's so much type casting in the function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion EMiller, one of the sticking points here is that these rules change constantly and we enforce strict SDLC, so I cannot update production logic on the fly. I would need some way to store this logic somewhere else but then use this logic  within the python code.

Comment: @Jarrod are you saying that you need to query the rules from some other dataset to effectively update the function while the code is running?

Comment: Exactly. The rules change every few months and usually a lot of them not just one or two. Deployment to prod takes some time and we need a way to update logic without redeploying a whole app.

Comment: don't use `apply` when vectorized functions are available